# super + space does not change language ubuntu 18.04 unity

Tags: unity, 18.04, shortcut-keys, launcher, input-language

I've upgraded from 16.04 -18.04, installed unity desktop and uninstalled gnome.

But I am not able to change my input language with shortcut key <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. On click of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> it shows the launcher with their respective number.

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 18.04 switching to GNOME, it seems that even the default Unity shortcut to switch keyboard layout isn't supported anymore.

I experimented different customized shortcuts for `Next/Previous Input Source` in `Settings > Text Input`, and found that shortcuts using <kbd>space</kbd> require either <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> to work, e.g. <kbd>ctrl+shift+space</kbd>. So the defaults  <kbd>super+space</kbd> and <kbd>super+shift+space</kbd> simply don't work at all.

**Solution**

You are still free to choose usual combinations like <kbd>super</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or modifier-based combinations like <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> (Windows-style). Be careful with shortcuts relying solely on <kbd>alt</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd> though, as they may open the Command, Launcher or Keyboard Shortcuts pop-up depending on how long you hold them.

For instance, on my Japanese keyboard I'm using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>muhenkan</kbd>, as it's also possible to reuse special keys.