# super+space stopped toggle language

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

Up until a week ago or so, I could use `super+space` to toggle between English and Swedish. Then it stopped working for some reason. I have tried different key-combinations but no matter what I cannot toggle the input source.

Have anyone experienced something similar?

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989036/superspace-not-working-on-unity-17-10) is something, but that did not help me. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071046/super-space-does-not-change-language-ubuntu-18-04-unity), it has not worked at all for others, but for me `super+space` has worked up to recently and now no key-combination works.

Other short commands work fine.

Comment: Check first under Settings - Keyboard, Typing. Maybe these keybindings are not anymore set to default?

Comment: I did a reset to default and that did not help. The command for `next source` was `super+space`